# jqPlot axes and legend is not rendering properly in exported image

Tags: jquery, css, image, jqplot

my jqPlot is rendering properly but when it is exported as an image, the axes text and legend labels are not rendered properly in the image. The text is moving right.

Here is my actual plot

[image: Actual plot]

Here is the exported image

[image]

Is it possible to apply some CSS to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by applying text-align:left css to the graph container div.